# Using H-bridge gate drivers to drive MOSFETs in non PWM applications

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, bootstrap

I am using IR2110 to drive a highside MOSFET which I intend to use to control the charging of a lithium ion battery (disconnecting it from the charger once full). I am not using any PWM control because the battery will be constantly charging. Just making the HIN pin of the IC high when I want to charge the battery and low when I want to disconnect the charger. Can H-bridge ICs work in this type of application where pwm is not involved or should I consider an alternative bootstrapping circuit? The diagram below shows my circuit. In my simulation, though the HIN voltage is constant, the output is oscillating. Please help me fix this.[image]

Comment: For starters, Vboot won’t charge, so you need to supply your on floating voltage for it. Infineon has an app note for non PWM operation for IR2110/2113.

Comment: @winny pls send me the link

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-HV_Floating_MOS_Gate_Drivers-ApplicationNotes-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4626c1f3dc3016c47de609d140a

Comment: @winny thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work in a DC application like yours because the bootstrap capacitor will discharge over time (microseconds), thus the high-side FETs will not remain on.

You could build a charge pump to maintain the bootstrap voltage, but it would be just as easy to use that to drive the FETs since you probably don't need the sub-us speed the PWM driver can operate at.

Comment: thank you. Will look into the charge pump